# How to describe the Language which accepts all binary strings divisible by 4 (in binary, divisible by 100)?

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I'm trying to write an inductive proof to show that my DFA accepts all binary strings which are divisible by 4 (divisible by $100_2$). Part of this proof is describing the language which machine $M$ accepts.

So far I've written the language as:

$\{0, 1\}^*\{00\}$

Because any binary string when interpreted as a binary number is divisible by 4 iff its last two digits are $00$.

However I'd like to exclude the empty string from this.

Should I write it as $(\{0, 1\}^* - \{\varepsilon\})\{00\}$? To get rid of the empty string from the set of all binary strings.

Comment: Just make the number start with $1.$ We usually assume the starting digit of a number is not zero.

Comment: @Thomas: Unless the number itself is 0.

Comment: But $0$ doesn’t end in $00.$

Comment: Is the binary string corresponding to zero written $0$, $00$, $000$ or is it empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most natural representation of numbers as binary strings is to represent $0$ by the empty string and all other numbers by a string starting with $1$.
In this way, the numbers divisible by $4$ can be represented by the language $1\{0,1\}^*00 \cup \{\epsilon\}$.

EDIT (answer to the comments). The problem is that the sentence "binary string when interpreted as a binary number" is not clear, because for instance, $011$ is a binary string but is **not** a binary number. If you decide to remove all the leading $0$'s, then each number has infinitely many binary strings representing it. For instance, the number $3$ would be represented by all binary strings of the form $0^k11$, with $k \geqslant 0$. Similarly, the number $0$ would be represented by all binary strings of the form $0^k$,
with $k \geqslant 0$. Note that the case $k = 0$ corresponds to the empty string. If you adopt this convention, the solution should be modified to
$$
0^*\bigl(1\{0,1\}^*00 \cup \{\epsilon\}\bigr)
$$

Comment: You could also make it $1\{0,1\}^*00 \cup \{0\}$ though

Comment: @maritsm The idea is to represent an integer $n$ by the shortest string $u = u_k \dotsm u_1u_0$ such that $n = \sum_{0 \leqslant i \leqslant k} 2^i$.

Comment: sure, but that is not how the language OP describes represents 0... there is no need to reimagine the representation of numbers in binary for this problem

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my previous comment, for clarification I am asking, suppose we have to define a *unique*  binary rep for each number, the most common approach will let 0 be 0 right?

Comment: (+1)btw, I think it’s a great answer